# Trying to install node-fetch but it results in an error

Tags: node.js, discord, node-fetch

I started to mess around with discord bots and I would need node-fetch for the tutorial which I started learning from.

I'm simply trying to run: (to install node-fetch)

```
npm install node-fetch
```

Which results in an error seen below.

This is the actual error from the log files:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')
     at Link.matches (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\node.js:1107:41)
     at Link.canDedupe (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\node.js:1061:15)
     at PlaceDep.pruneDedupable (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\place-dep.js:468:14)
     at PlaceDep.placeInTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\place-dep.js:329:14)
     at PlaceDep.place (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\place-dep.js:216:10)
     at new PlaceDep (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\place-dep.js:73:10)
     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:990:31
     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
     at Arborist.[buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:990:8)
at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:218:7)
```

What can I do here to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Don’t think you need to install anything, just try fetch(…)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a lower version. Try `npm install node-fetch@2` it worked for me. Before that do `npm cache clean –force` which clears the cache.

Comment: Same error :| ...

Comment: Try ```npm cache clean –force``` and then try npm i node-fetch.

Comment: Same error sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, was an npm cache issue if I understand correctly, check this out:

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1603

Comment: The link is good.  Please. also, add sufficient text here to explain it.